# Application windows become undisplayable

Tags: 14.04, gui

I've searched around and cannot find anything that matches my situation with Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop. I have a dual monitor system and my application windows disappear after a sleep. Here it is step-by-step:

1. I have applications open and running
2. My displays go to sleep
3. I wake up the system with mouse movement
4. Windows are gone, but main gui bar and launcher are visible and working
5. I press Alt + Tab and applications are selectable
6. I select any of the app icons
7. Application window does not become visible
8. Clicking the app icon on the launch bar also does not make the window visible

At this point I have to right click the icon on the launch bar and select quit to use any of the previously available apps.

I also don't know enough to know if I'm using Unity or not.

EDIT: I found out something interesting about all this today. I can use Alt + Tab and select the invisible application, then hit Alt + F7 and use the left cursor key to bring the window into the visible area. For some reason the windows are being pushed off the screen to the right when the screen sleeps; this is incredibly annoying.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and by default it comes with Unity. I have the same problem and only to say that workaround (ALT+TAB and ALT+F7) works for me. I have a laptop and when my external screen is setup on left I don't have that problem (instead all window that was on laptop screen after waking up they are on the external screen, but I can easily access them, they are not hidden).